# !asyncSupported exception when switch from Jetty 7 to Jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty, war

we recently upgraded our jetty version.  when we did this both of our legacy gui war files, which no one has modified in some time, stopped working correctly.  I believe I hunted the root cause to the proxy (used to proxy to a restful interface on another port), any call to the proxy throws the exception:

```
 IllegalStateException: !asyncSupported
```

I'm not sure why this would occure with 1.9 but not with the old jetty.  I can't build the war file currently, it was a mess that only one developer could ever build, but I trid unzipping it with jetty -x and ading to the servlet section of the web.xml file this:

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

and then rezipping it with jar c command.  that didn't seem to help, though now i get exceptions in my jetty log fhile while before they would only show in the browser.

can anyone tell me what to do to activate async support and/or why the switch in jetty would cause this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, the evolution of the spec ...

- Jetty 7 was Servlet 2.5 (no async there)
- Jetty 8 was Servlet 3.0 (async introduced) - spec was vague on what was default, so Jetty defaulted to `async-supported == true`
- Jetty 9 is Servlet 3.1 (even more async) - the spec was clarified, and jetty chose its default poorly.  The default according to the spec is `async-supported == false`

That's why you didn't have to specify async-supported in the past, but now you do.

Bug about this [bugs.eclipse.org/410893](https://bugs.eclipse.org/410893)

Commit: [9bf7870c7c8a209f2660f63c14dd4acb62b07533](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=9bf7870c7c8a209f2660f63c14dd4acb62b07533)

Comment: so...is there a way for me to default jetty to this in the jetty configuration rather then the war filse; sicne I can't rebuild the war at this point?

Comment: sorry, there's no quick solution for this.

Comment: feel free to file a bug asking for this enhancement. Could be possible via a custom WebAppContext attribute on a deployable context xml

Answer (score 6):

My exception is the same to you. then I put "`<async-supported>true</async-supported>`" append to every servlet and filter. it work well.
For excample

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.annotation.AnnotationCometdServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

the other hand. if you used jetty9.x. you'd better update your comet jar to version 3.0.x or later. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't (yet) put this as a comment, but I'd like to add: If you are having this trouble and have added the async-supported tag as appropriate (or are using Jetty 8), make sure your filters *also* support async or are not used with the servlet in question.

Comment: Nice addition! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Java based config you may use

```
@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(name = "HelloWorld",urlPatterns = { "/MyServlet" },asyncSupported =true)
```